# Errors in changing old default theme to new theme

Tags: drupal

Hi i have installed drupal commerce kickstart. Initially it contains Demo store with default theme. Next i installed new free theme for my store. It still contains old theme's contents images and slides.
The new theme's contents and other effects are not coming.
What did i Missed?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to clear the demo contents from the existing commerce kickstart installation. You could use [Commerce Reset](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_reset) module, if not already exist, to clean it.

Regarding your new theme, have you installed the supported content types and content to show within the new theme? If you are using a free theme, i must say, you should read the theme instruction to setup this. Most free themes doesn't provide the dummy content with it and you need to create supported content types, views, blocks and then do the necessary configurations to make it works.

If you need further help please provide the theme link you are using to build your site.